# Множественные запросы к базе

Tags: база-данных

Меня интересует вопрос, как лучше сделать более производительную выборку из базы по внешнему ключу (индексы и связи настроены).
К примеру у меня есть таблица с объектами и каждая выборка дает большой набор данных.

Затем мне мне нужно наполнить объект из другой таблицы (по внешнему ключу).
Конечно не у всех объектов могут быть подобъекты.
Формат объекта

```
{
 "id" : 100,
  "Name": "Test",
..
"SubObjects" : [....]
}
```

приходит в голову только 2 варианта:
1. Выборка все объектов и выборка всех подобъектов. (минус - приходиться закидывать базу множественными запросами).
2. Сделать только 2 запроса. Первый так же выведет все объекты, а второй все подобъекты. Затем соединить это в коде на сервера. (минус - второй запрос выведет большое количество объектов, которые работают в памяти и их  надо обрабатывать в коде через перебор всей коллекции. Linq в моем случае.)

Второй вариант нравится мне больше, но может есть у кого-то другие обоснованные решения?

Answer (score 0):

Классика - сделать один запрос с [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). Запрос будет выглядеть примерно так

```
Select * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.key == table2.foreignkey
```

У вас выберутся все данные из основной таблицы с заполненными данными из дочерней таблицы, если данные в дочерней таблицы имеются для основной таблицы. Если в дочерней таблице данных не будет, столбцы дочерней таблицы будут заполнены значением  null.

Далее уже работаете на клиентской стороне, группируя объекты по основной сущности(по полю ключ). В итоге получаете все основные объекты и массив его подобъектов, если они у него имеются.

Comment: боюсь эта классика выдал мне больше строчек/потребует больше объема чем мой второй вариант.

Comment: @Dev, разумеется, будет больше строчек, так как для каждого join-а будет несколько записей. Почему у вас главный критерий только память? ваш второй вариант подразумевает join на клиенте, что менее эффективно для CPU, чем join на самом сервере. Почему вы не хотите например, возвращать пачками запись, чтобы решить вопрос с памятью?

Comment: потому как JOIN на клиенте в этом варианте будет так же. Только объем данных будет больше от сервера.

Comment: _потому как JOIN на клиенте в этом варианте будет так же_. У меня к вам предложение, замерить скорость выполнения алгоритма с JOIN на сервере, и на клиенте и сравнить результаты для примерно 50000-100000 записей в основной таблице. Вы увидите разницу в скорости выполнения(сетевые затраты должны свести к минимуму, то есть сервер должен быть близко располагаться)